# Probability 5th grade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In 1880 population was 1 billion. In 1920 population was 2 billion. In 1980 population was 4 billion.  Following this trend would the population be 6, 8, 10, or 12 billion in 2020? Answer on official answer key is 8 billion. How is this number calculated?

Comment: Did you verify the numbers are correct? I'd guess this is a problem on exponential growth, but as stated in your question the growth is not exponential.

Comment: What does this have to do with probability?

Comment: According to the Terms of Service, "Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age. No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address)."

Answer (score 2):

You assume population follows an exponential trend:

$$P = a \, e^{b t}$$

where $P$ is the population (in billions), $t$ is time (in years), and $a$ and $b$ are unknown constants.  You can convert this to a linear equation by taking logs:

$$\log{P} = \log{a} + b t$$

We have an overdetermined system, with $3$ equations and $2$ unknowns

At $t=0$ (1880), $P=1$ at $t=40$, $P=2$; then we have:

$$0 = \log{a} + b (0) $$
$$\log{2} = \log{a} +b (40) $$
$$\log{4} = \log{a} +b (100)$$

Then we perform a least squares by considering the matrix

$$A = \left (\begin{array}&1 & 0 \\ 1 & 40\\1 & 100 \end{array}\right )$$

and vector

$$b = \left (\begin{array}&0\\ \log{2} \\ \log{4} \end{array}\right )$$

The least squares solution is

$$\left (\begin{array}&\log{a} \\ b \end{array}\right )= (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$$

so that, sparing you the details, the best fit is

$$P(t) = 2^{(3/38)(1+t/4)}$$

therefore, our best guess is in 2020,

$$P(140) = 2^{(3/38)(36)} \approx 7.17\, \text{billion}$$

so $8$ billion is the best answer.

Comment: Whoops, so not a 5th grade approach.  Sorry.  Hopefully useful still.

Comment: This problem is asked on the 5th grade level.  Perhaps you can give a new answer as this is not helpful to the OP.

Comment: @Jeff: I became aware of this after I posted the answer (note the comment).  As I put sufficient effort into the answer, I kept it here for anyone else who might find it useful.

Comment: It is a rather clever solution (obviously coming from you), however it may scare the people off who are learning math at 10 years old, assuming they haven't learned how to take transposes & inverses.  i did find it useful so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The population increased by a factor of 4 from 1880 to 1980, and although you don't have any reason to assume it will do the same from 1920 to 2020, you don't really have anything else to go on. So assume it, and conclude the population will be 8 billion.